# When one label animates, the second label automatically animates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

As per the title, I DO not want that to happen.

I have 2 separate labels and I want to make them flash provided an if statement is met. But whenever either label animates, the second label automatically follows to animate. I tried to test it by just changing the foreground color of the label and it works. The problem seems to occur only when I use the animation. Can anyone please help to spot my problem please. Tnks.

```
void AlertAnimation(Label label)
        {
            label.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty,  
                new ColorAnimation
                {
                    To = Colors.Red,
                    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
                    AutoReverse = true,
                    RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(3)  
                });
        }

void calc()
{
    if (maxValue > slider1.Value)
                {
                    AlertAnimation(label10);
                    //label10.Foreground = Brushes.Red; //it works when I use this line. 
                }

    else if (minValue < slider2.Value)
                {
                    AlertAnimation(label11);
                    //label11.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                }
}
```

Comment: It is *probably* because the Foreground property of both labels is actually set to the same SolidColorBrush object.

Comment: Can you help tell how i could better construct the code? Cos based on what you said, I am assuming I need to create 2 separate solidColorBrush objects and conflicts with reusing the code. Please advice. Thanks.